# Symbol lookup error undefined symbol, but all symbols seem to be present

Tags: linux, ld, elf

An executable seemingly can't resolve a symbol in a linked library. The relevant output of LD_DEBUG=libs shows that the correct library is loaded:

```
6557:     /usr/lib/libcharon.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: auth_class_names (fatal)
                /usr/libexec/ipsec/charon: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libcharon.so.0: undefined symbol: auth_class_names
```

nm -D shows that the symbol auth_class_names is defined:

```
nm -D /usr/lib/libcharon.so.0|grep auth_class_names
        U auth_class_names
```

EDIT: Outputs of ldd added:

```
/usr/lib# ldd /usr/lib/libstrongswan.so
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6ecd000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libdl.so.2 (0xb6ec2000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/librt.so.1 (0xb6eb3000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc.so.6 (0xb6d78000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.3 (0xb6f25000)
/usr/lib# ldd /usr/lib/libcharon.so
    libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libm.so.6 (0xb6ea6000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6e86000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libdl.so.2 (0xb6e7b000)
    libcap.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libcap.so.2 (0xb6e70000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc.so.6 (0xb6d35000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.3 (0xb6fa6000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libattr.so.1 (0xb6d27000)

# nm -D /usr/lib/libstrongswan.so|grep auth_class
00036a50 D auth_class_names
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> nm -D shows that the symbol auth_class_names is defined

No: it shows that `auth_class_names` is *un*defined in `libcharon.so`.

> libstrongswan provides the auth_class symbol, but libcharon doesn't reference it.

Wrong again: `libcharon.so` *does* reference the symbol.

> `ldd /usr/lib/libstrongswan.so`

That's *not* what you want. You want `ldd /usr/lib/libcharon.so`.

Your problem is most likely that neigher `libcharon.so`, nor the main executable were linked against `libstrongswan.so`, so when you dynamically load `libcharon.so`, `libstrongswan.so` is nowhere to be found; hence the loading fails with undefined symbol.

There are several possible solutions, ordered from more correct to more hacky:

1. Link `libcharon.so` against `libstrongswan.so`. Loading `libcharon.so` will load all of its dependencies (which will now include `libstrongswan.so`, and the symbol will be found).
2. Link `charon` binary against `libstrongswan.so`.
3. Dynamically load `libstrongswan.so` *before* you load `libcharon.so`.
4. `LD_PRELOAD=libstrongswan.so`

Comment: Thanks, you are correct in terms of wrong version of apps and libs

Answer (score 1):

Actually "U" means, that symbol is undefined. What does ldd show on your `libcharon.so.0`? `libstrongswan.so.0` is where you should find `auth_class_names`.

Comment: Hi, indeed the libstrongswan provides the auth_class symbol, but libcharon doesn't reference it...